# How to find energy levels formula for symmetric triangular potential well

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, solid-state-physics, nanoscience

As some of you already know that the asymmetric triangular potential well has the energy level [image]

where an here refers to the airy function a1 =2.338, a2=4.088, a3=5.521 and a4= 6.787 and V=eFz (F here refers to electric field).

However in the case of symmetric triangular potential well where V = |eFz|, how to find or derive the energy levels here? Any ideas?